# Nginx - forwarding to multiple servers at once?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to configure nginx in the way it sends request to n well known locations and returns response as soon as it gets 20x from one of them?

If it helps, I have 100% guarantee that either exactly one host responds or there will be no successful response at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what 'gets 20x' is? A proper configured load balancing pool will remove servers not responding within a timeframe.

Comment: Yeah, the keyword is: loadbalancing. I just realized the only thing I need to do is to set up load balancer in front of that n server and nginnx will do the rest. Thanks.

Comment: OK, sound good. I'll add an answer with a setup I have, adding a timeout parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a load balancing pool where a server not responding within a timeframe is removed. Using sticky sessions using ip_hash where the same ip-address goes back to the same server. Useful for maintaining sessions if sessioninformation is not shared across servers. nginx have a well documented [page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) with the various options.

```
http {
    upstream my_pool {
        ip_hash;
        server 1.2.3.4 weight=3 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
        server 1.2.3.5 weight=4 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
        server 1.2.3.6 weight=3 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=20s;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name domain.org www.domain.org;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://my_pool;
        }
    }
}
```